# How is "wing thickness" defined?

Tags: aircraft-design, wing

In the answers to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19016/could-airliners-wings-be-thinner-if-no-fuel-were-stored-in-them) about wing thickness, there were many references to wing thickness as a percentage (ranging from 6.5% to 13.5%).

What is that a percentage *of*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The wing thickness is basically the distance between the upper and lower surface of the wing (or airfoil).

`[image: Airfoil geometry]

Source: NASA.

The wing thickness is usually given as a percentage of the wing (or airfoil) chord(the distance between the leading and trailing edge). This is to make it a non-dimensional quantity for ease of comparison across different scales.

Comment: The picture really helps with understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

From the image in the answer you link to:

> thickness in percent of chord

and the chord (length) is the distance between leading edge and trailing edge of the airfoil of the wing.