# What happens to the neutral point of a fighter jet during supersonic flight?

Tags: aircraft-design, supersonic, stability

I understand that for a fighter aircraft, it would have to be inherently unstable. To do this I believe that the neutral point needs to be aft of the cg. I was told that during supersonic flight this relationship might be different. What would change in supersonic flight?

Comment: Would the answers to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53381/why-does-aircraft-stability-increase-when-it-transitions-from-subsonic-to-supers) be of any help to answer this one? I feel we can mark your question as a duplicate - if you disagree, please edit your question and point out why it is **not** a dupe.

Comment: Yes I agree, thank you for the link appreciate it!